# Op-Amp Filter with Output Capacitance

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

I've been looking into different ways an op-amp can be used for signal filtering and came across the following circuit.

[image]

I would like to solve for the transfer function, \$G=\frac{v_{in}}{v_o} \$ for this circuit (we can assume an ideal op-amp for simplicity). My initial guess was to divide up the gain multiplication into two parts: \$G=\frac{v_{1}}{v_{in}}\frac{v_{o}}{v_1} \$, where \$v_1\$ is the amplified output of the op-amp.

Going with this, the first part of the transfer function, \$\frac{v_{1}}{v_{in}}\$, to my understanding would just be a standard lowpass op-amp configuration, hence:

$$\frac{v_{1}}{v_{in}}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{1+(sC_1R_2)}$$

The second part of the transfer function, \$\frac{v_{o}}{v_1}\$, is where I found some confusion. To me, it seems like a simple voltage divider between \$v_1\$ and \$v_o\$ should work, but this would not include \$R_3\$ in the equation at all. I also thought that perhaps I need to create a Thevenin equivalent circuit for this part, but I'm not really sure how you could do that for this scenario. But, assuming the voltage division here is valid, I get:

$$\frac{v_{o}}{v_{1}}=\frac{sC_2}{(1+sC_2R_4)}$$

resulting in a final transfer function of the form:

$$G(s)=-\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{1+(sC_1R_2)}\right)\left(R_4\frac{sC_2}{(1+sC_2R_4)}\right)$$

So, is this the right way to go about solving this circuit? Is splitting up the circuit essentially into two parts valid here? Is a simple voltage division enough to solve \$\frac{v_{o}}{v_1}\$, without \$R_3\$ being a factor?

Any insight would be much appreciated, please let me know if I've messed things up completely as well.

Comment: If the op-amp is acting as an ideal voltage source, R3 is simply seen as a load and has no bearing on the downstream transfer function. I didn't check your equations but your method is sound.

Comment: Certainly, this is a second-order lowpass - however with rather bad properties (two real poles only), The same an be achieved with two simple (passive) RC sections. There are many other (and much better) 2nd-order lowpass topologies.

Comment: @LvW This is interesting, I agree that it should be a second order LP, but the transfer function is of the form G~s/(s^2), which if memory serves right is the generic form of a second-order bandpass.

Comment: JTaft121, sorry you are right. It is a simple bandpass. I did not look carefully enough to the circuit. Anyway - my comment remains the same: A bandpass with a rather bad selectivity (two real poles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHuaFl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0\space\text{V}\tag3$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 + I2 == I3 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == V2/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I4 == V3/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, V2,
    V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/R1, 
  I2 -> -(((R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) Vi)/(R1 R3 (R4 + R5))), 
  I3 -> -((R2 Vi)/(R1 R3)), I4 -> -((R2 Vi)/(R1 (R4 + R5))), 
  V2 -> -((R2 Vi)/R1), V3 -> -((R2 R5 Vi)/(R1 (R4 + R5)))}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\cdot\text{R}_x}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\text{R}_x}=\frac{\text{R}_x}{1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\text{s}}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\text{R}_x}{1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_5\right)}=$$
$$-\frac{\text{R}_x}{1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\text{s}}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\text{s}\right)}\tag7$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=-\frac{\text{R}_x}{1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\text{j}\omega}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\text{j}\omega}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\text{j}\omega\right)}=$$
$$-\frac{\text{R}_x}{1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\omega\text{j}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\omega\text{j}}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\omega\text{j}\right)}\tag8$$

So, the absolute value if given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_x}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\omega\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\omega}{\text{R}_1\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\omega\right)^2}}\tag9$$

And the argument:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_x\omega\right)-\arctan\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_5\omega\right)\tag{10}$$

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanation @Jan , I had not considered using Laplace transforms to solve the problem. If I am reading your solution correctly, I believe we have the same transfer function, with Rx being R2 in my answer and R5=R4.

Comment: @JTaft121 correct!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. An ideal op amp has zero output impedance: it behaves like a voltage source. The load resistor R3 is immaterial in that idealized model. You can of course use a more sophisticated model that includes the output impedance of the op-amp, and then it’d be obvious that R3 plays a role. But you’re not using such a model.